# Index was outside the bounds of the array, but refer to 0 index while array have items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, indexoutofrangeexception

I have exception "Index was outside the bounds of the array",
but there 22 Model items and index of array that i refer to is 0 (Model[0])

[image: My code]

Comment: what line the stacktrace shows ?

Comment: Maybe the exception is not from that line.

Comment: @AidOnline01 Can you provide code for cshtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was nothing to do with "Index out of array exception". Error was from another place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try foreach loop instead of for loop.

```
@foreach(var product in Model)
{
     <span>@product.Link<span>
}
```